# Visual Studio 2008 - Project without DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, project-reference

I need to add a reference to a project to do some reflection. But it seems that this project doesn't have a .DLL file (even after building it).

Can this happen?

Comment: No it can't happen. If this is a .NET project and you successfully compile it you will get an assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're adding a reference to a project that you have the source code for, just add the project to your solution and add the reference to the project.  Always prefer referencing projects over referencing binaries if the option is available.

If you're adding a reference to something that isn't already a project in the solution, then you'll (of course) need the binary.

Don't try to add a reference to a binary that's generated by a project that's already in the solution.  That's just silly.  :)

Comment: Yes sure, the project is situated in another solution. Your first solution is ok, it will keep me running at least, until I find why there isn't any DLL :/

Comment: It is entirely legitimate and, in some cases, recommended, for a single project to be shared amongst multiple solutions.  It isn't a hacky approach, and in fact may be the "right" solution.

Answer (score 3):

The project could be an executable or website project for a couple of possibilities to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an ASP.NET Website? they won't compile into dll's but an ASP.NET Web Project will.

Comment: It's not an ASP .NET Website. It's a Windows application.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a `Class library` project there should be a DLL as the output. I suggest checking the `Application` tab of the project settings and see what `Application Type` it is.
You can also check the `Compile` tab to check where the assembly will be created.

Comment: If it's a `Windows Application` it'll produce an exe file, not a DLL.